# dotnet ef database update not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-identity, .net-core

I cant update my identity database with `dotnet ef database update`. I get no errors but the database is not updated.

I've created a migration with `dotnet ef migrations add TerminalId`and it seems to work fine since I now have `20170522123744_TerminalId.cs` and `20170522123744_TerminalId.Designer.cs` in the migrations-folder. If I do `dotnet ef migrations list` I get nothing though.

Here's my csproj:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
    <TypeScriptCompileBlocked>true</TypeScriptCompileBlocked>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="FluentEmail.Mailgun" Version="2.0.3" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc" Version="1.1.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug" Version="1.1.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.BrowserLink" Version="1.1.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.DotNet">
      <Version>1.0.0-*</Version>
    </DotNetCliToolReference>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Comment: Are you looking at the correct database? Might be that EF has created a new database on LocalDB if it couldn't find a connectionstring.

Comment: Yes, the database already exist. The initial update worked

Comment: And you didn't change configs or other projects in the meantime? You're running the tool from the right location and with the right configuration?

Comment: Nope :( the weirdest thing is that i dont get any migrations when i do the list command.